# thread in python vs C# vs Ruby

Tags: c#, python, ruby, multithreading, closures

I think I've found something which C# and Ruby can do but Python can not

in C#:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    new Thread(() => { Console.Write(i+" "); }).Start();
Console.ReadLine();
```

in Ruby:

```
for i in 0...100
    Thread.start{
        print i + ''
    }
end

gets
```

Any ideas? Could you rewrite the above code in python? the output should be similar to C# and Ruby: **has duplicate numbers**.

**Edit**
The output is 100 times of print, with duplicate numbers. If you define a class or a new method, you only get 100 times of print without duplicate numbers. I know getting duplicate numbers is meaningless, I just want to use python to achieve the same effect as C# and ruby.

sample output of C#:

```
3 3 3 3 5 7 8 8 10 10 12 12 13 14 17 17 17 18 20 20 22 23 24 24 25 28 28 29 29 3
1 31 33 33 34 36 38 38 38 41 41 41 42 44 45 45 46 49 49 50 50 52 52 55 56 56 56
58 59 59 60 61 64 64 64 66 66 67 68 69 72 72 72 73 74 76 76 78 78 81 81 82 83 84
 84 86 86 87 89 89 90 93 94 94 95 95 97 97 99 99 100
```

sample output of Ruby:

```
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

**Why do I want duplicate numbers:**
the output of the C# and ruby code have duplicate numbers. That's because, the main thread are changing the value of i, so some children threads might print the same number. **Main thread and the children threads are referencing to the same variable i**.
Sometimes this is useful: the main thread changes the variable, the children threads all get updated variable.
But How could we do this in Python?

Comment: Extends threading.Thread sounds like a much *better* design pattern than the alternatives.  It's nicely encapsulated, and very clean.

Comment: What do you mean with duplicate numbers? You mean you get "1" 100 times, then "2" 100 times, etc. or what?

Comment: @agf, I changed WriteLine(i) to Write(i+" "). an example output of C#: 3 3 3 3 5 7 8 8 10 10 12 12 13 14 17 17 17 18 20 20 22 23 24 24 25 28 28 29 29 3
1 31 33 33 34 36 38 38 38 41 41 41 42 44 45 45 46 49 49 50 50 52 52 55 56 56 56
58 59 59 60 61 64 64 64 66 66 67 68 69 72 72 72 73 74 76 76 78 78 81 81 82 83 84
 84 86 86 87 89 89 90 93 94 94 95 95 97 97 99 99 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the different threads to sometimes see the same value of `i` then you need to pass in a mutable object and mutate it:

```
import threading

def action(arg):
    print arg[0],

mutable = [0]
for i in range(100):
    mutable[0] = i
    threading.Thread(target=action, args=(mutable,)).start()
```

This has nothing whatsoever to do with whether or not you define a separate class for the thread, it is purely down to how you share the value between the threads. A global variable would work to mess up your threading in the same way.

Sample output:

```
0 1 2 3 5 5 6 8 9 9 11 11 12 1314 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 3
0 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 39 39 40 41 43 44 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 53 53 54 55 56
5758 59 60 61 62 64 65 6666 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 8
4 85 86 87 89 90 90 92 93 93 94 95 96 9898 99
```

Comment: Sometime it's not "mess", it is useful. If really want they share the same variable

Comment: In Python you just have to share the same object instead of sharing the same variable. This is usually also true in other languages as you want to be sure there is appropriate locking around access to the value: Python's GIL ensures you don't have to worry about the locking for simple objects but you should still worry for anything mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually you can:

```
>>> import threading
>>> def target():
...     print 123
...
>>> threading.Thread(target=target).start()
123
```

Your example would look like next:

```
>>> def target(i):
...     print i
...
>>> for i in xrange(100):
...     threading.Thread(target=target, args=(i,)).start()
...
0
1
2
3
<and so on>
```

Comment: Not a rewrite of the ruby or C# code. But anyway, I know it is possible to use multithreading without defining a new class in Python. thanks.

Comment: All the threads will be writing to stdout in parallel, the output will be garbled. You need to put a lock around the print if you expect clean output, but even then the order is not predictable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not the same output" but I wanted to note you can even declare it inline like in Ruby and C# if you really want to (in Python 2.6 or later with `from __future__ import print_function` or in Python 3): `threading.Thread(target=(lambda i: print(i)), args=(i,)).start()`

Comment: @agf, I didn't know that it could be done as inline. It is said that lambda in python had to be a single expression(not a statement).

Comment: That's correct. `print` is a function in the situation I described, so `print(i)` is an expression. In normal Python 2 where `print` is a statement, it's not possible. I still think it's a "Bad Thing" to do it inline, I just wanted to point out it is possible if what you want to do is really simple enough that it might make sense.

Comment: @agf, see my new edit. the output should be the same as C# and ruby. there should be duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
import threading

def action(arg):
    print arg

for i in range(100):
    threading.Thread(target=action, args=(i,)).start()
```

Comment: Sure, without a new class, but with a new method. much better.

Comment: @Tyler: You mean extending `threading.Thread` and redefining the `run` method, sure it's possible but depending on the use case, eg. in this example it will be an overkill to do that.

Comment: Yes, a class is overskill. But we'd better omit that method too. Because something does matter. run the C# and ruby code, you get a lot of duplicate prints. That's because they use inline closure instead of a new method.

Answer (score 1):

Edited again:

> I think I've found something which C# and Ruby can do but Python can not

No this **has duplicate numbers** and looks very much the same like your Ruby/C# code.

```
import threading
import sys

for i in xrange(100):
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: sys.stdout.write('{0}\n'.format(i))).start()
```

-

```
14
15
17
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: I think your answer is right. just not so pythonic. Yes I know the pythonic way could not produce duplicate numbers, so you have to do it this way. thank you!